# How do I copy the newest file in a directory somewhere else from the command line in windows vista

Tags: scripting, windows-vista

I have a directory of many files in Windows Vista.  I'd like in a batch script to be able to pick the newest file and copy it to another location.  Any ideas how I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the for command to invoke a directory listing that is sorted by date, and use it to set an environment variable, if you set the same variable to each file, then it will end up being set to the latest file.

put this into a batch file:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do set LATEST=%%I
echo "%LATEST%"
```

then you can use the move command to move that file to wherever you want it.

```
move "%LATEST%" wherever
```

EDIT 10-Feb-2011: fixed to handle filenames with spaces in them.  The fix is to use "delims=" to disable tokeninzing on space. Thanks to Dave Potts for the fix.

Comment: This _almost_ solves it.  The problem is for long file names with spaces in them (I work with accountants, sorry).  Working on fixing that.

Comment: Here's the fix: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do set LATEST=%%I
echo %LATEST%`

Comment: Hmm, I used this before and it worked. Yesterday I've tried it on another script, but it seems it won't work with files in different folders :(