# Show all files in directory and select the latest creation date one with windows command line

Tags: file, command-line, scripting, directory, command

is there a way with windows command line to list all the files from a specific directory and then select the name of the file that has the newest creation date.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This iterates through a directory listing and sets an environment variable to each file in order by date; the last one set would be the newest file:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do set LATEST=%%I
echo "%LATEST%"
```

Then you could copy the file like so:

```
copy "%LATEST%" destination
```

Based on the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469234/how-do-i-copy-the-newest-file-in-a-directory-somewhere-else-from-the-command-lin).

**EDIT:** I also got the `%%I was unexpected at this time` error when executing this directly through the command prompt, but it worked fine from within a batch file. You could create a batch file with the above and it should work.

Comment: i get 

%%I was unexpected at this time.

Comment: i get an error message saying : %%I was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Edited the above; I got the same error when I pasted the command into the prompt, but from within a batch file it works fine.

Comment: its works but i have a problem, i created a batch file and inserted the following code :  for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d /od') do set LATEST=%%I
echo "%LATEST%" but now the LASTEST turn to be my cmd file instead of my real lastest file

Comment: I found a another way, in the ('dir [enter your directory path here] /b /a-d /od'), so like this your batch fil is not in your directory so it doesnt appear as your lastest

Comment: try %%I for batch files, %I for command line. Also I believe the dir command should omit the dash, ie `('dir /b /ad /od')`. works-for-me.